# How to store a value in a conditional statement and call it in ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

Method

```
def myname(generate_name)
  if generate_name
    name = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6)   
    name //ex:abcdef
```

Call

```
myname(true)    //output abcdef
myname(false)   //expected output abcdef
```

In my code, I have to use `myname(true)` to generate unique name every time the function is referred.

Question: I need the value "abcdef" to be the output when I call `myname(false)`

Comment: Do you want to create a random name of 6 characters every time?

Comment: yes. exactly, every time when the method is called with true as parameter

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is the expected output? That is currently not working? Is the code in your question the bavahor you want or the current behavior?

Comment: Where is `myname` method defined? You could simply store this value as an instance variable, right?

Comment: the current behaviour is whenever i call myname(false), the name is returning as empty value. @MarekLipka sorry just new to ruby.. trying to understand a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
def myname(re_generate = false)
  @_myname = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6) if @name.nil? || re_generate
  @_myname
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Store this value as an instance variable:

```
def myname(generate_name)
  return @name unless generate_name
  @name = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6)
end
```

Comment: somehow 
myname(false) returns empty string with the above code. when myname(true) is called for the first time, i want to store that value and return it when myname(false) is called.

Comment: "somehow myname(false) returns empty string with the above code." No, [it does not](https://repl.it/repls/DisloyalAmazingBloatware).

Answer (score 0):

Try the method like below -

```
def myname(generate_name)
  return SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6) if generate_name

  'abcdef'
end
```

Comment: thank you, when myname(true) is called for the first time, i want to store that value and return when myname(false) is called.

Comment: I got your question wrong. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651908/7903039](This answer) is perfect.